# Function "Interval_point"

Tags: python, ipython, python-3.5

I have a task for my pyton101 course at uni which is as follows:

Create a function interval_point(a, b, x) that takes three numbers and interprets a and b as the start and end point of an interval, and x as a fraction between 0 and 1 that determines how far to go towards b, starting at a.

Examples (IPython):

```
In [ ]: interval_point(100, 200, 0.5)
Out[ ]: 150.0

In [ ]: interval_point(100, 200, 0.2)
Out[ ]: 120.0
```

I came up with this:

```
def interval_point(a, b, x):
"""takes three numbers and interprets a and b as the start and end point
of an interval, and x as a fraction between 0 and 1 that determines how
far to go towards b, starting at a"""
if (a == b):
    return a
if (x == 0):
    return a
if (x > 0):
    return((abs(a - b) + a) * x)
```

It worked for most of the tests that the automated test system looks for but it could't deal with a or b being a negative value.

Can someone suggest how I could make a function that does negative numbers as well as being able to handle if a is negative and b is positve.

Here was the report from the automated test system:

## Test failure report

### test_interval_point

```
def test_interval_point():
    #if x=0, we expect to get value a back
    assert s.interval_point(1.0, 2.0, 0.0) == 1.0

    #if x=1, we expect to get value b back
    assert s.interval_point(1.0, 2.0, 1.0) == 2.0

    #test half-way, expect (a+b)/2
    assert s.interval_point(1.0, 2.0, 0.5) == 1.5

    #test trivial case of a=b
    a, b = 1., 1.
    x = 0.0
    assert s.interval_point(a, b, x) == a
    x = 1.0
    assert s.interval_point(a, b, x) == a
    x = 0.5
    assert s.interval_point(a, b, x) == a

    #test for negative numbers
    assert s.interval_point(-2.0, -1.0, 0.5) == -1.5

    #test for negative numbers
    assert s.interval_point(-2.0, -1.0, 0.0) == -2.0

    #test for negative numbers
    assert s.interval_point(-2.0, -1.0, 1.0) == -1.0

    #test for positive and negative limits
    assert s.interval_point(-10, 10, 0.25) == -5.0
```

Comment: The number you are looking for is `a + (b - a) * x`

Comment: Yeah, you are over-engineering this. You use the absolute difference for *absolute distance*. If you just want a relative distance from x, then you just need the difference. Or, think of it this way, "a plus what number is b?", `a + x = b` <=> `x = b - a`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Goyo's comment, I would personally not check for edge-cases:

```
def interval_point(a, b, x):
    return (b - a) * x + a
```

This should work for all values of `a`, `b` and `x`, including your special cases `a == b` and `x == 0`. If there is any performance gain by doing those checks, it will be negligable in most cases.

This version will also work if `x` is not in `[0, 1]`, for example:

```
>>> interval_point(100, 200, 2)
300
>>> interval_point(100, 200, -1)
0
```

Which is probably acceptable. If not, your function should check that `0 <= x <= 1`, because now your implementation of the function will return nothing if `x < 0`